# Wrapper for Google_Service_Calendar as a Symfony service

Tags: php, dependency-injection, session, wrapper, symfony3

My app interacts with Google Calendar. This Service wraps [`Google_Service_Calendar`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar.html):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class GoogleCalendarService extends \Google_Service_Calendar
{
    public const CALENDAR_ID = '123example@group.calendar.google.com';

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session) {
        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setAccessToken($session->get('google_access_token'));
        parent::__construct($client);
    }
}
```

I have the feeling that having the session as a dependency is not a good practice. For a user of that service, it is absolutely not clear that the access token needs to be set in the session.

I could probably add some Exceptions for the case that it is not set, but I wonder whether there is a better way?

Comment: should `$session` be an optional parameter? if not, then under what conditions would an exception be warranted?